# How can i get the most borrowed books?

Tags: mysql

i'll just get straight to the point. my database is like this

every book is stored at reading_materials and every book has its own unique Accession No no matter how many copies it has (disregard the field name 'Copies'). when a student or personnel borrows a book, the data is inserted at the borrow table. my problem now is, how can i get the most borrowed books on the borrow table.

can someone help me pls?

my database is like this:

#### borrow

```
Trans_ID PRIMARY KEY
A_Accession_No FOREIGN KEY references reading_materials(Accession_No)
B_Student_No
DateBorrowed
DateReturned
Penalty
```

#### reading_materials

```
Accession_No PRIMARY KEY
Date_acquired
Title
Copyright
Available
```

#### book_author

```
B_Accesion_No FOREIGN KEY references reading_materials('Accession_No')
Author_ID FOREIGN KEY references author(Author_ID)
```

#### author

```
Author_ID PRIMARY KEY
Name
```

*i apologize for my bad english and if some of u won't find this not very clear

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? It definitely looks like one... What have you tried so far?

Comment: yeah it is. i havent tried anything yet. what i want to do is to check all the titles in the reading_materials and get their accession nos in the borrow table and count how many of them are in there but i don't how should i query it. i'm still a noob at sql. T^T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT a.Accession_No, a.Title, COUNT(b.a_accession_NO) as NoOfTimesBorrowed
FROM Reading_Materials a LEFT JOIN borrow b ON a.accession_No = b.a_accession_NO
GROUP BY a.Accession_No
ORDER BY NoOfTimesBorrowed DESC
LIMIT 5
```

this will select the `TOP 5` and sorted from the most borrowed book.

Comment: tnx alot! u really save my day! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *, COUNT(SELECT Trans_ID WHERE A_Accession_NO = Accession_NO) AS BorrowedCount FROM reading_materials
ORDER BY BorrowedCount DESC

That query should get you the most borrowed books in descending order and tell you how many times each one has been borrowed.